# How to filter values in a point array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a constantly feeding point array with a length of 4, and want to filter certain "outliers" in the array.

I'm creating a VR/AR app with Opencvforunity and Unity.
Using a live feed from the webcam, I have an 4-length points array which updates and contains x, y 2d coordinates, representing the four corners of a tracked object. And I'm using them as source values to draw a Rect in unity.

Each slot in array contains data such as this:
{296.64151, 88.096649}

However, Unity throws errors and crashes when the a value in the array has

- negative values (sometimes happens because of tracking error)
- large values exceeding the canvas size (same reason, currently using 1280 x 720)

An example of a "bad value" will be like this :

{-1745.10614, 46.908913} <- negative / big value on X

{681.00519, 1234.15828} <- big value on Y

So I have to somehow create a filter for the array to make the app to work.
The order should not be altered and the data constantly updates so ignoring/skipping bad values will be optimal. I'm new to C# and I have searched but no good luck for "point array"

Here's my code:

```
Point[] ptsArray = patternTrackingInfo.points2d.toArray();              
pt1 = ptsArray[0];
pt2 = ptsArray[2];     
pt3 = new OpenCVForUnity.CoreModule.Point(ptsArray[2].x + 5, ptsArray[2].y + 5);                               
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
        cropRect = new OpenCVForUnity.CoreModule.Rect(pt1, pt3);
        }
```

pt1 represents the left-top corner and pt2 for right-bottom.
I heard that the right bottom point is exclusive in OpenCV itself so I tried to add a new point to that(pt3), but still crashing - so I believe it is not related to that matter.

Any suggestions for creating a filter for a point array will be very much helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your requirement, but you have for each `Point` `X`and `Y`, just filter it in the for loop you have there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create a new list of Points and loop through the existing list, adding only the valid points to the new list. Then that becomes the list that you convert to an array for your OpenCV calls.

```
List<Point> filteredList = new List<Point>();

for(int i = 0; i < patternTrackingInfo.points2d.Count; i++)
{
    if(/*Do your check here*/)
        continue;

    filteredList.Add(patternTrackingInfo.points2d[i]);
}

Point[] ptsArray = filteredList.toArray();              
pt1 = ptsArray[0];
pt2 = ptsArray[2];     
pt3 = new OpenCVForUnity.CoreModule.Point(ptsArray[2].x + 5, ptsArray[2].y + 5);                               

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    cropRect = new OpenCVForUnity.CoreModule.Rect(pt1, pt3);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I used a method similar to your suggestion but now I am facing an out of memory error. I placed this for loop in the update() function in Unity script and now trying to figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: I would need to see the new for loop. Can you edit your question to include this?

Comment: turns out that I made an mistake creating the if statement. figured it out. thank you!